# Android TextView id with a variable?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, textview

In my Android application, is there a way I can set the text to a textview by using a variable as part of the id?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView+i, "" + realtimeData.get(i).id);
            }
```

I do have the TextViews declared in the layout xml as textView1, textView2, etc... and can access them with the static name.  My issue is I do not know how many objects will be in my list.  I do not want to display more than 5, but if there are fewer than 5 its ok for the TextView value to be left blank.

Comment: No you can not do this :) R.id is compile time generation.

Comment: I know this cant be done.  I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
     views.setTextViewText(getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", getPackageName()), "" + realtimeData.get(i).id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Luksprog , However I feel that "i<6" isn't the right way to go, Instead use `ViewGroup.getChildCount() and ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)` so you can control your amount of textviews better.

Answer (score 0):

### Less Issues

Using `getIdentifier()` was causing me grief so I ended up with the following:

```
String idName = "companyName";   // The id name of your resource.

int resourceId = R.id.class.getField(idName).getInt(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Provided you keep a thigh control over your R file to make sure your IDs are consecutive, you could try something like:

```
for (int i = R.id.firstTextView; i <= R.id.lastTextView; i++){
    views.setTextViewText(i, "" + realtimeData.get(i).id);
}
```

which would allow to just add IDs to the R file without having to modify your code to change the hardcoded `6` number.

Just to prove my point:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/testStart" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/test2" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/test3" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/testEnd" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" />
```

generates:

```
    public static final int button1=0x7f070004;
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070005;
    public static final int test2=0x7f070001;
    public static final int test3=0x7f070002;
    public static final int testEnd=0x7f070003;
    public static final int testStart=0x7f070000;
```

Adding at a later stage:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/test4" />
```

right before

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/testEnd" />
```

immediately changes R.java to:

```
    public static final int button1=0x7f070005;
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070006;
    public static final int test2=0x7f070001;
    public static final int test3=0x7f070002;
    public static final int test4=0x7f070003;
    public static final int testEnd=0x7f070004;
    public static final int testStart=0x7f070000;
```

Comment: You cannot control the ids.  They are generated at compile time by the ADT and there is no way you can predict or guarantee them.

Comment: It works when you use @+id, IDs are recompiled in consecutive order. However, I must say that the design would be fragile.